# Feature Toggling for automated tests in Ruby web app

Tags: ruby, automated-tests, integration-testing

We are working to build an integration test framework at my current company - and one of the challenges I have yet to answer is how do we handle the need to toggle features on and off without completely restarting the server in our test environment.

So - that is my question to the community - has anyone recently conquered this issue with a third party tool they might enlighten me upon, or any other feedback that may be given would also be awesome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If it's a third party service/tool you're looking for, you could try [LaunchDarkly](https://launchdarkly.com/).

It wouldn't be very hard to roll your own solution though: you could create a new `Toggle` model, where each record represents one feature toggle with a boolean on/off. If you're worried about hitting the database too often, you could cache the entire collection at startup; and then add code to update the cache when toggles get updated.